# KeyError: 0, TFF strange error in multi-outputs model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I have a multi outputs FedAvg model that I implemented just like the  Tutorial and a bit extends to reach the multi outputs version.

My model function is like below,

```
  def model_fn(self):
    fed_model = CNN()
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      fed_model,
      input_spec=self.preprocessed_sample_dataset.element_spec,
      loss=[tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
            tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()],
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
```

the Keras model's last lines are like the below snippet code.

```
def CNN():
    inp = Input(shape=(13055,))

    x = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(x)
    a = Dense(units=unit, activation=activ, name='a')(x)
    v = Dense(units=unit, activation=activ, name='v')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs={'a': a, 'v': v})

    return model
```

and my TFF dataset is built like the below.

```
        data = collections.OrderedDict((('x', x),
                                        ('y', collections.OrderedDict((('a', a),
                                                                       ('v', v))))))


        client_train_dataset[client_name] = data

    train_dataset = tff.simulation.datasets.TestClientData(client_train_dataset)

    sample_dataset = train_dataset.create_tf_dataset_for_client(train_dataset.client_ids[0])
    sample_element = next(iter(sample_dataset))

    def preprocess(dataset):
        NUM_EPOCHS = 5
        BATCH_SIZE = 32
        PREFETCH_BUFFER = 10

        def batch_format_fn(element):

            """Flatten a batch `pixels` and return the features as an `OrderedDict`."""
            return collections.OrderedDict(
                x=reshape(element['x'], [-1, 13055]),
                y=collections.OrderedDict((('a', reshape(element['y']['a'], [-1, 1])),
                                           ('v', reshape(element['y']['v'], [-1, 1])))))


        return dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS).batch(BATCH_SIZE).map(
            batch_format_fn).prefetch(PREFETCH_BUFFER)

    preprocessed_sample_dataset = preprocess(sample_dataset)

    def make_federated_data(client_data, client_ids):
        return [preprocess(client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x)) for x in client_ids]

    federated_train_data = make_federated_data(train_dataset, train_dataset.client_ids)
```

when I use the learning API like the one below

```
      self.iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
          self.model_fn,
          client_optimizer_fn=lambda: SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
          server_optimizer_fn=lambda: SGD(learning_rate=1.0))

      print(str(self.iterative_process.initialize.type_signature))
```

I got an error of KeyError: 0 that makes me confused, I do name the outputs same as the `y` collection.OrderedDict

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amir/Documents/CODE/Python/FedGS/main.py", line 401, in <module>
    obj = EmoRec(attr)
  File "/Users/amir/Documents/CODE/Python/FedGS/main.py", line 139, in __init__
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: SGD(learning_rate=1.0))
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging.py", line 270, in build_federated_averaging_process
    model_update_aggregation_factory=model_update_aggregation_factory)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py", line 696, in build_model_delta_optimizer_process
    aggregation_process=aggregation_process)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py", line 381, in _build_one_round_computation
    @tf.function
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/impl/wrappers/computation_wrapper.py", line 479, in __call__
    fn_to_wrap, fn_name, parameter_type, unpack=None)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/impl/wrappers/computation_wrapper.py", line 216, in __call__
    result = fn_to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 764, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3289, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.autograph.impl.api.StagingError: in user code:

    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py:395 _compute_local_training_and_client_delta  *
        client_output = client_delta_fn(dataset, initial_model_weights)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging.py:93 reduce_fn  *
        output = model.forward_pass(batch, training=True)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/dataset_reduce.py:28 _dataset_reduce_fn  *
        return dataset.reduce(initial_state=initial_state_fn(), reduce_func=reduce_fn)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py:389 forward_pass  *
        return self._forward_pass(batch_input, training=training)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py:373 _forward_pass  *
        batch_loss += loss_wt * loss_fn(

    KeyError: 0
```

and when I pass a loss function class in model_fn instead of two in a list, I got the error below,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amir/Documents/CODE/Python/FedGS/main.py", line 400, in <module>
    obj = EmoRec(attr)
  File "/Users/amir/Documents/CODE/Python/FedGS/main.py", line 139, in __init__
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: SGD(learning_rate=1.0))
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging.py", line 270, in build_federated_averaging_process
    model_update_aggregation_factory=model_update_aggregation_factory)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py", line 696, in build_model_delta_optimizer_process
    aggregation_process=aggregation_process)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py", line 381, in _build_one_round_computation
    @tf.function
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/impl/wrappers/computation_wrapper.py", line 479, in __call__
    fn_to_wrap, fn_name, parameter_type, unpack=None)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/impl/wrappers/computation_wrapper.py", line 216, in __call__
    result = fn_to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 764, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3289, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code:

    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/optimizer_utils.py:395 _compute_local_training_and_client_delta  *
        client_output = client_delta_fn(dataset, initial_model_weights)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging.py:93 reduce_fn  *
        output = model.forward_pass(batch, training=True)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/framework/dataset_reduce.py:28 _dataset_reduce_fn  *
        return dataset.reduce(initial_state=initial_state_fn(), reduce_func=reduce_fn)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py:389 forward_pass  *
        return self._forward_pass(batch_input, training=training)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py:360 _forward_pass  *
        batch_loss = tf.add_n([loss_fn(y_true=y_true, y_pred=predictions)] +
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:155 __call__  **
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:259 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1743 binary_crossentropy
        y_pred = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch(y_pred)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1431 convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch
        value, dtype=dtype, dtype_hint=dtype_hint, name=name)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1441 convert_to_tensor_v2
        as_ref=False)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py:163 wrapped
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1566 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:339 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:265 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:283 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:457 make_tensor_proto
        _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    /Users/amir/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:334 _AssertCompatible
        raise TypeError("Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead.")

    TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead.
```

can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyError` is coming from [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/610843c724740e1b041837cc93501b609fb05d8f/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py#L373), the code is looking at the `predictions` coming out of the model using an integer `i`.

However, the Keras model is defined with a `dict` output:

```py
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs={'a': a, 'v': v})
model.predict_on_batch(tf.ones(shape=[1, 13055]))
>>> {'a': array(...), 'v': array(...)}
```

Try defining the `tf.keras.Model` using a `list` (matching the position of the `loss` list pass to `tff.learning.from_keras_model`).

```py
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[a, v])
model.predict_on_batch(tf.ones(shape=[1, 13055]))
>>> [array(...), array(...)]
```

This should allow TFF to match the loss functions, labels, and model output.

Comment: I did change the model as you mentioned, but it did not work. 
When I have one loss_fn (not in a list) it gave me a `TypeError: Expected any ... ` and when I have two loss_fn (in a list) it gives me `KeyError`. `

Comment: my input_spec is <PrefetchDataset shapes: OrderedDict([(x, (None, 13055)), (y, OrderedDict([(a, (None, 1)), (v, (None, 1))]))]), types: OrderedDict([(x, tf.float64), (y, OrderedDict([(a, tf.int64), (v, tf.int64)]))])>

Comment: How about the second error? Can you look at it? I dig up a little bit but I could not find anything that points out my problems related to TFF framework.